# Ajax.Begin Form, CallBacks not firing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an extremely weird issue with Ajax unobtrusive forms.

The form submits to the controller, but the callbacks are not firing.

I have checked the config settings, I have all the required scripts.

Here is an example of one of the forms.

Located in a js file

```
var AdminSaveComplete = function (xhr, response) {
}

var AdminSaveFailed = function (xhr, response, message) {
}

var AdminSaveSuccess = function (result, response, xhr) {
    $('#li1 .Slide_Dwn_Pan').slideUp();
    $("#li1 .Bullet").removeClass("DropBullet");
    $('#li2 .Slide_Dwn_Pan').slideDown();
    $("#li2 .Bullet").addClass("DropBullet");

    $('#breadCrumbs').html('<li> New Event Set-up | Type</li>');
}

var AdminSaveBegin = function  () {
    alert('OnBegin');
}




@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitEventAdmin", "Events", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnComplete = "AdminSaveComplete",
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnFailure = "AdminSaveFailed",
        OnSuccess = "AdminSaveSuccess",
        OnBegin = "return AdminSaveBegin()"
    }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
```

I have forms in partial views that I load into a main view, one after another, they are not embedded within each other.

Comment: Does it work if you define your functions like `function AdminSaveComplete(xhr, response) {
}` and you have the microsoft unobtrusive ajax script included on the page? Are there any errors in the console? What version of jQuery do you have loaded?

Comment: @AshleyMedway Makes no difference on how it is defined. I have latest jQuery enabled, the script is included on the page, there is no errors, the ajax call happens, it hits break points in the controller and the data is sent through, and saved in database. It was working and then just stopped when I started adding multiple forms, each Ajax form has it's own callback functions

Comment: Give the forms IDs? Make sure they are not nested?

Comment: @AshleyMedway They are not nested, trying the ID's now, will let you know